# Populating a VSO Build vNext build variable from MSBuild

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have an MSBuild task that populates a variable that I would like to use later in the build process (specifically as an argument in a command line build step).

Is there any way to access an MSBuild variable in subsequent build step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [##vso[task.setvariable]value](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)  logging command from your MSBuild task to pass the variable to VSO like this:

```
<Message Text="##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvariable;]$(MyMSBuildProperty)" />
```

You can use the variable in a subsequent build step by using `$(myvariable)` in the input fields of the command line build task.